# Get all the month year(MM-YY) dates between two dates

Tags: apex

Is there a way to get all the dates between two dates

if i have a

```
start date: Feb 2014
end date :  April 2014
```

---

```
Output:
Feb 2014
March 2014
April 2014
```

I have this code:

```
    startYear = 2014;
    startMonth = 02; //Feb
    endYear = 2014;
    endMonth = 04; //April
    Date startDate = Date.newInstance(startYear,startMonth,01);
    Date endDate =   Date.newInstance(endYear,endMonth,01);
    Integer range = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate) + 1;
    Integer year1 = startDate.year();
    Integer year2 = year1 + 1; // in case the range extends year
    monthYearSet = new Set<String>(); // 'YYYY|MM'
    Set<Integer> yearSet = new Set<Integer>(); 

    //list all the date in the range
    Integer tempMonth = startMonth;
    for (integer i = startMonth; i <= range; i ++){
        if (math.mod(i,12) == 0){
            for (integer y = 1 ; y <= 12; y++){
                monthYearSet.add(year2 + '|' + y);
                if(y==range){
                    yearSet.add(year1);
                    yearSet.add(year2);
                    break;
                }                       
            }
            yearSet.add(year1);
            yearSet.add(year2);                
            year1++;
            year2++;
            tempMonth = 1;
        }
        else {               
            monthYearSet.add(year1 + '|' + tempMonth); 
            tempMonth++;
        }            
    }
```

monthYearSet would be the result of this loop.

this code is not working if:

```
start date and end date had the same year and same month
if end date: year > start date: year
```

Do you have any idea on how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got caught in a loop of adding fixes and ended up over-complicating things a tad. This generates the set of strings with the `YYYY|MM` format that you're after:

```
Date d1 = Date.Today();
Date d2 = Date.Today().AddMonths(4);
Set<String> monthYearSet = new Set<String>();

while(d1 < d2)
{
    monthYearSet.add(d1.Year() + '|' + d1.Month());
    d1 = d1.AddMonths(1);
}

System.Debug(monthYearSet);
```

Comment: That short?!!! I'm so ashamed right now. Thanks for your help @LaceySnr!!! You helped me a lot!!!!

Comment: We've all been there. Generally when it feels like it should be simple and it appears to be getting complicated it's best to go back to first principals and give it another crack :)